# Will parent transaction failed too if nested transaction failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the code with nested transaction

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    deleteCustomer();
    insert_customer_function();

    // No exception throw. Success
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}

void insert_customer_function() {
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        insertCustomer();
        // Exception throw somehow...
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

I was wondering, will `deleteCustomer` be commited, or be rolled back, if the nested transaction `insert_customer_function` failed?

From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html , It seems that

> Note that an inner transaction might commit (using the RELEASE
>   command) but then later have its work undone by a ROLLBACK in an outer
>   transaction. A power failure or program crash or OS crash will cause
>   the outer-most transaction to rollback, undoing all changes that have
>   occurred within that outer transaction, even changes that have
>   supposedly been "committed" by the RELEASE command. Content is not
>   actually committed on the disk until the outermost transaction
>   commits.

It seems that

- If outer doesn't commit, even inner is committed, both outer & inner will be rolled back.

But what if,

- If outer commit, but inner doesn't commit, will both outer & inner will be rolled back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an exception, in case the called method fails, so the calling one gets an error and the "parent" transaction will rollback too.

By throwing an exception, you force an error, which is then back propagated to the caller,  which handles it in the try catch block.

A quick reference: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=0443546CEE776318BF6D21552A9D1864?recipeId=75&recipeFrom=ViewTOC

Comment: Thx. In that case, do you mean "If outer commit, but inner doesn't commit, will both outer & inner will be rolled back? - No" ?

Comment: I mean so: if inner doesn't commit, outer will receive an error thrown from inner. Therefore, outer will catch the exception and won't commit too. You need to add a **catch** to outer, to catch the exception thrown by inner in case of rollback.

Comment: So, if I do not throw exception from insert_customer_function, there might be risk that I will end up with empty table because deleteCustomer will be committed?

Comment: if you do not throw an exception from insert_customer_function it means that it was committed, so the insertion/s took place. if the deletion didn't throw an exception, it also was successful.

Comment: But may I ask you why do you delete and then insert? couldn't you just replace? (it will insert a new record if there isn't or update an existing one) - [REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html)

Comment: Since I m doing "sync" with flat file data. flat file data more contain completely different info rows than db. Hence, it is easier to delete all n insert all.